Android Studio - Do not concatenate text displayed with `setText`. I'm not using setText AND part of the string is a calculated value
So i built a beginner calculator thing to learn and i'm getting this warning on this line:
Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders.
tvResult.text = "Result is " + "%.2f".format(result)

The line works just fine. And I understand strings.xml and I've used @string/var for things in activity_main.xml like
android:text="@string/str_add"
But I don't have setText for tvResult, i have a hint
android:hint="@string/str_result"
I can change that from hint to text, but how do i concatenate that with a dynamic value to not get the warning?
Thanks

Kotlin acutally does call setText behind the scenes (it's just obscured from you by Kotlin's property access syntax.). What this is really telling you is you should have a string resource with the formatted parameters that you would then load using Resources#getString instead of having a hard-coded string.
